# Configure kubectl to use a remote Kubernetes cluster on windows

Tags: windows, kubernetes, config, kubectl, chocolatey

I am trying to configure kubectl to use a remote Kubernetes cluster on my local windows machine following the ["Install with Chocolatey on Windows"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-with-chocolatey-on-windows) tutorial. However, I am not quite sure how to fill the config file. It should look like this somehow:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

or this, but I got like no idea how to fill those "variables"

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://123.456.789.123:9999
    certificate-authority-data: yourcertificate
  name: your-k8s-cluster-name
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: your-k8s-cluster-name
    namespace: default
    user: admin
  name: default-context
current-context: default-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    token: your-login-token
```

Comment: What variables specifically?

Answer (score 1):

This variable must be provided by your k8s cluster administrator with special kubeconfig file.
After that you can access to you cluster with `--kubeconfig <path to you kubeconfig file>` options:

```
kubectl cluster-info --kubeconfig ./.kube/config -v=7 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true --alsologtostderr
```